# use href tag for different html pages but with same url id in express

Tags: node.js, express, url, parameters, ejs

i'm trying to switch between home and profile page for same user with click on each button. also except change between home and profile,id should stay the same.[image]

but after click on profile button only id will be changed and it uses profile as id
(i used ejs as format for my views/html pages)
[image]
any idea how can i fix it?is that even possible?

there is my nav code:

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper  teal darken-4">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">BAZAART</a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn teal lighten-1" href="home"> <i  class="material-icons right">home</i> home</a></li>
        <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn teal lighten-1" href="profile">profile <i class="material-icons right">account_box</i></a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

homeController:

```
exports.sendReqParam = (req, res) => {
    let userHome = req.params.userHome;
    res.render("home", { name: userHome });
    // res.send(`This is the homepage for ${userHome}`);
    
   };
   exports.respondWithName = (req, res) => {
    let paramsName = req.params.myName;
 res.render("profile", { name: paramsName });
   }
```

main.js

```
app.get("/profile/:myName",  homeController.respondWithName);
    app.get("/",  homeController.respondInfo);
app.get("/home/:userHome", homeController.sendReqParam)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was recently making a blog website, where I write a post and it displays it on the home page. But if we wanted to go to the specific post page, instead of making another separate page for each new post, we made a `post.ejs` page instead, and later to acces the specific post we simply used something called lodash. I'll show you an example of it, so it makes more sense, and I'll show you the code we used.

So the example is this, I go to the `compose.ejs` page and I write a random post: `title=Post, content=A random lorem ipsum`
and lets say we write another post: `title=Another post, content=Another random lorem ipsum`

Okay so now everytime we write a blog post it sends us to the home page (where we currently are) and it shows the two blogs posts. If we wanted to go to the specific url of the post, we simply write this link `localhost:3000/posts/Another post` hit enter and it takes us to the second post we wrote.

And this is the code we used inside the `app.js`:

```
app.get("/posts/:postName", function(req, res){
  const requestedTitle = _.lowerCase(req.params.postName);

  posts.forEach(function(post) {
    const storedTitle = _.lowerCase(post.title);

    if (storedTitle === requestedTitle) {
      res.render("post", {title: post.title, content: post.content});
    }
  });
});
```

In the `app.js` code, we see in the app.get `/posts/:postName` and this is just the name that is going to show in the url, `:postName` is like a variable and it will store whatever the user writes.

In the second line, we use lodash to rewrite what the user wrote to what we want, for example if the user wrote `AnoTheR POst` it will automatically change it to `another-post`, and we store it in a constant called `requestedTitle`.

Next is a forEach loop on a `posts` array (where we store every post), and this is just to go throught every post and check the names.

In the 4th line, we are again using lodash for the same thing, but this time arround for the title of each individual post, and storing it in a constant called `storedTitle`.

And last, an if statement, where if both the names are the same then it will render the `post.ejs` page, and we just pass down the title and content from the selected post using this code `, {title: post.title, content: post.content}`.

And this is the code we used inside the `post.ejs`:

```
<%- include("partials/header") -%>


<br>
<div class="card">
  <h2 class="card-header"> <%= title %> </h2>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text"> <%= content %> </p>
  </div>
</div>


<%- include("partials/footer") -%>
```

As you can see this `post.ejs` isn't hard to explain, the top and bottom lines where it says `include("partials` are just the header and footer templates I use, just to save time coding. Whats inside is what the `post.ejs` will render when it gets called.

I hope it wasn't that confusing, I'm still learning to code and I hope it helps you with what you are looking for. I think this isn't the exact answer for your question, but I think it will help you navigate your way throught.

If you need more explanation or help, this is my instagram: @cemruniversal, I'm always happy to help if I can.

Edit: 30 minutes after original post

I think I found a way it could work, I'll show you a piece of code from the same blog website.

Whenever I want to compose a new post I use this code:

```
app.get("/compose", function(req, res){
  res.render("compose");
});
```

And obviously there is a form for you to write the post, and after you submit, it sends you to the home page, and saves the post. For that I used this piece of code:

```
app.post("/compose", function(req, res){
  const post = {
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody
  };
  posts.push(post);
  res.redirect("/");
});
```

I had an idea for your website, what if when you pressed the Profile button, it renders a specific page on your site, and when you press another button it renders another page. It could work, wouldn't it?

Please try it out and tell me how it went.

Comment: thanks for your help!i'll try solution this weekend and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this:

```html
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper  teal darken-4">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">BAZAART</a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn teal lighten-1" href="/home"> <i  class="material-icons right">home</i> home</a></li>
        <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn teal lighten-1" href="/profile">profile <i class="material-icons right">account_box</i></a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: then it responds without Id like this:localhost:8080/profile. but it should be like this:localhost:8080/profile/lily

Comment: Then you should append `lily` in href via JS